# What change in xml-rpc in android application to use HTTPS communication

Tags: android, https, xml-rpc

I use XML-RPC Server and client with android application from this link: http://www.codeforest.net/how-to-build-php-xml-rpc-server-client-and-android-app communication is through HTTP. Can you explain me what and where I must change in Android code to communicate through HTTPS. Thanks (I read many articles on stackoverflow, but I can´t know how to use it in my android code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution and it´s work fine:

```
//In class XMLRPCClient
    public XMLRPCClient(URI uri) {
                    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
                    registry.register(new Scheme("http", new PlainSocketFactory(),
                            80));
                    registry.register(new Scheme("https", new EasySSLSocketFactory(), 443));

                    postMethod = new HttpPost(uri);
                    postMethod.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");

                    // WARNING
                    // I had to disable "Expect: 100-Continue" header since I had 
                    // two second delay between sending http POST request and POST body 
                    httpParams = postMethod.getParams();
                    HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(httpParams, false);
                    this .client = new DefaultHttpClient(
                            new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(httpParams, registry),
                            httpParams);
                }
```

And must add to org.xmlrpc.android 2 classes EasySSLSocketFactory and EasyX509TrustManager

EasySSLSocketFactory:

```
package org.xmlrpc.android;

/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;

import org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.LayeredSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

/**
 * This socket factory will create ssl socket that accepts self signed certificate
 *
 * @author olamy
 * @version $Id: EasySSLSocketFactory.java 765355 2009-04-15 20:59:07Z evenisse $
 * @since 1.2.3
 */
public class EasySSLSocketFactory implements SocketFactory, LayeredSocketFactory {

    private SSLContext sslcontext = null;

    private static SSLContext createEasySSLContext() throws IOException {
        try {
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new EasyX509TrustManager(null) }, null);
            return context;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private SSLContext getSSLContext() throws IOException {
        if (this.sslcontext == null) {
            this.sslcontext = createEasySSLContext();
        }
        return this.sslcontext;
    }

    /**
     * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory#connectSocket(java.net.Socket, java.lang.String, int,
     *      java.net.InetAddress, int, org.apache.http.params.HttpParams)
     */
    public Socket connectSocket(Socket sock, String host, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort,
            HttpParams params) throws IOException, UnknownHostException, ConnectTimeoutException {
        int connTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getConnectionTimeout(params);
        int soTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getSoTimeout(params);
        InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
        SSLSocket sslsock = (SSLSocket) ((sock != null) ? sock : createSocket());

        if ((localAddress != null) || (localPort > 0)) {
            // we need to bind explicitly
            if (localPort < 0) {
                localPort = 0; // indicates "any"
            }
            InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(localAddress, localPort);
            sslsock.bind(isa);
        }

        sslsock.connect(remoteAddress, connTimeout);
        sslsock.setSoTimeout(soTimeout);
        return sslsock;

    }

    /**
     * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory#createSocket()
     */
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }

    /**
     * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory#isSecure(java.net.Socket)
     */
    public boolean isSecure(Socket socket) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @see org.apache.http.conn.scheme.LayeredSocketFactory#createSocket(java.net.Socket, java.lang.String, int,
     *      boolean)
     */
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException,
            UnknownHostException {
        return getSSLContext().getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------
    // javadoc in org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory says :
    // Both Object.equals() and Object.hashCode() must be overridden
    // for the correct operation of some connection managers
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return ((obj != null) && obj.getClass().equals(EasySSLSocketFactory.class));
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return EasySSLSocketFactory.class.hashCode();
    }

}
```

EasyX509TrustManager:

```
package org.xmlrpc.android;

import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

class EasyX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager
{
    public EasyX509TrustManager(KeyStore keystore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
        super();

    }
@Override
public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException
{

}

@Override
public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException
{

}

@Override
public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
{
return new X509Certificate[0];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should just work fine with https. You just need to change the URL to start with https.

Note: If the SSL certificate is not a trusted one, then you might need to write your logic to deal with that. But if the certificate goes along with your devices, no other change is required.

Comment: Yes, but my certifikate is not a trusted. Can you help me? what i must change in the source?

Comment: @Pedro Perfect solution. I was also facing the same problem and getting XML-RPC Error, but as I tried your solution, now it works like a charm.